# How can I convert a set of numeric strings to a set of integers?

Tags: python, string, int, set

I have a set

```
set1= { '1', '2' }
```

I want to convert '1', '2' to int  , like this :

```
set_new = { 1, 2 }
```

How can I do this in python?

Comment: Have you tried *anything*?

Comment: Try to write some code.

Comment: People are seriously upvoting this? [*facedesk*](http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/224/5/c/facedesk_gif_by_katetls-d684dcx.gif)

Answer (score 11):

Use **[map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)** function

Demo:

```
>>> set1= { '1', '2' }
>>> set2 = set(map(int, set1))
>>> set2
set([1, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use set comprehension:

```
>>> set1={'1', '2'}
>>> set2={int(item) for item in set1}
>>> set2
{1, 2}
```