# converting a set() to an int python

Tags: python, type-conversion, integer, set

So my question is how can you (or if it can be done at all) convert data type of set to an integer?

for example: (IS A TOY EXAMPLE TO EXPLAIN WHAT I'M TRYING TO DO)

```
A = [1, 2, 6, 4, 3]
a_set = set(A)
a_int = a_function(a_set)
print(type(a_int))
```

Output:
`<class 'int'>`

So any assistance in the conversion of a set() to an int would be greatful. I have seen this [how-can-i-convert-a-set-of-numeric-strings-to-a-set-of-integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30423104/how-can-i-convert-a-set-of-numeric-strings-to-a-set-of-integers) which I thought may help but no luck. So thanks in advance.

What I'm actually trying to do is that I want to return a set that has only one element inside it but I want to return it as an int.

Comment: `set` is a collection. `int` is a scalar value, hence attempting to convert a `set` to an `int` does not make much sense. You should elaborate on exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: `a_set = set(1)` is not valid.

Comment: @DeepSpace I am attempting the PermMissingElement problem from codility and I have used set difference to obtain the correct value but it is returning the value as a set with only one element and I want to convert that element into a int and return the int.

Comment: @Countour-Integral changed it

Comment: You claim to have a set with only one element, but your example set has *five* elements?

Comment: @superbrain is only a toy example, to help explain what I mean

Comment: Well it doesn't. Rather the opposite.

Comment: @superbrain I thought this was a site to help people and not nit pick at small mistakes :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not trying to covert a `set` to an `int`. You are merely trying to "pull" out the content of the set.

If you are certain the set contains only one element, you can use `.pop`:

```
print({1}.pop())
```

will output

```
1
```

If the set contains more than a single element, every call to `pop` will grab and return an arbitrary element from it.

Be careful, if the set is empty calling `pop` on it will raise a `keyError` exception.